# Hibernate : Update many-tomany intermediary table on Delete

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I am fairly new to Hibernate and do not fully understand how I should proceed to update an intermediary table.

I have a ManyToMany relationship between two tables : conferences & publications

POJO Publication.class :

```
private List<Conference> conferences;
...
 @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Conference.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
      CascadeType.MERGE })
  @JoinTable(name = "publications_conferences", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Publications_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Conferences_id"))
  public List<Conference> getConferences() {
    return conferences;
  }

  public void setConferences(List<Conference> conferences) {
    this.conferences = conferences;
  }
```

POJO Conference.class :

```
private List<Publication> publications;
...
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Publication.class, mappedBy = "conferences")
  public List<Publication> getPublications() {
    return publications;
  }

  public void setPublications(List<Publication> publications) {
    this.publications = publications;
  }
```

My table "conferences" contains duplicated records. My code check whether two Conference a,b have similar titles and deletes either a or b. Now, instead of deleting the reference (and therefore the record) in the intermediary table, I would like to update it this way :

Before deleting Conference "b":

```
|Publications_id|Conferences_id
-------------------------------
        c       |       a
        d       |       b
```

After deleting Conference "d":

```
|Publications_id|Conferences_id
-------------------------------
        c       |       a
        d       |       a        <----- update reference
```

I tried the following code :

```
 if (answer == 2) {
            deleteConferenceQ.setParameter("confId", confIdB);

            for (Publication pubB : publicationsB) {

              publicationsA.add(pubB); 
              pubB.getConferences().add(a);
              session.save(pubB);
            }

            int result = deleteConferenceQ.executeUpdate();
            tx.commit();
      }
```

But I receive a `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions`. Therefore I am wondering if what I do is correct.

**EDIT #1:** I replaced the previous code with :

if (answer == 2) {

```
            Iterator<Publication> pubBIter = publicationsB.iterator();
            while (pubBIter.hasNext()) {
              Publication pubB = pubBIter.next();
              pubBIter.remove();
              pubB.getConferences().remove(b);
              b.getPublications().remove(pubB);

              pubB.getConferences().add(a);
              publicationsB.add(pubB);

            }
            session.save(a);
            session.delete(b);
          }
```

I still have the previous Exception upon `session.save(obj)`

Can anyone help me with it ? Thanks

Comment: What if you just remove the publicationsA.add(pubB); from the loop?

Comment: @StanislavL I rewrote the code (EDIT #1), but still get errors ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JPA/Hibernate point of view, you shouldn't even think about the join table. You just need to maintain both sides of `@ManyToMany` relationship and let Hibernate manage the database. In your case it should come down to deleting one row and adding one row from the join table. Your code should look something like this

```
Publication pub = ...;
Conference confToBeRemoved = ...;
Conference confToBeAdded = ...;

pub.getConferences().remove(confToBeRemoved); // this implies equals() and hashcode() are properly implemented
confToBeRemoved.getPublications().remove(pub); // same here

pub.getConferences().add(confToBeAdded);
confToBeAdded.getPublications().add(pub);

// save all
```

Comment: Alright! In the first place I delete the conference using a   Query deleteConferenceQ = session.createQuery("delete Conference where Conferences_id = :confId");. Should I still delete it first like this, and then add/remove from lists ?

Comment: I still have the HibernateException about associating a collection with two open sessions. Actually, I don't see why there are two open sessions. In the beginning of the my method, I get open 1 session, and close it when it's done.

Comment: Don't use HQL to delete an entity, it isn't n sync with Hibernaye session and could be the reason for the exception you are getting.

Comment: Alright, I am now getting a ConcurrentModificationException. Is there something wrong adding/removing inside a "for (Publication pubA : publicationsA) {" ? I want to update every publication of the deleted conference. The previous exception was due to the session.save(obj) being inside the for loop.

Comment: In your `for` loop use iterator and `iterator.remove()` to avoid that exception

Comment: Thanks, I no longer have the concurrent exception. But the `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions`remains no matter what :-(

Comment: How are you getting the session, `factory.getCurrentSession()`? Try searching the web for the exception, there are plenty of hits so you might find something useful. I don't have any more ideas at this time.

Comment: No, i use openSession() because getCurrentSession() gives me a "Session is closed!" exception. Basically, I execute a "select" query in the beginning of the method, iterate through the returned list and add/remove the references. Anyway, thanks for your help :) If you have anymore ideas, dont hesitate !

Comment: Sounds like there's your problem, you should probably ask a new question to find out why current session is closed.